# Как сделать в мобильной версии чтоб не улетало?

Tags: html, css, jquery

имеется **Accordion.js**, при компьютере всё нормально работает, в мобильной версии есть баг.
Если выбрали 1 спойлер, где много текста, а потом нажали на другой спойлер где мало текста, резко прокрутка идёт в подвал сайта, а не на тот пункт который нажали.

Саму работу пока при клике на неё скролит сделал так временно:

```
$('.acc_section').click(function(){
        theOffset = $(this).offset();
 $(window).scrollTop(theOffset.top - 0);
```

})
Нажал на селект **.acc_section**  к нему скроллинг пришёл.
Если даже уберу код JQuery, то всё равно так происходит. Видимо из за количество символов связанно в спойлере...

Вот сайт где стоит аккордион [ссылка сайта](https://beautyhub.pro/faq)

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 0):

Добавил спойлеру ширину и всё встало отлично.

```
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
```